# How to detect mime type of files in python?

Tags: python, zip, mime-types

I have a problem such that i have zip files uploaded from forms and i want to detect the mime type of the files that contained in these zip files,i have no problem in extracting the files from the zip but the problem how to know the mime type of each file in this zip?Thanks

Comment: Are you on a unix system? You could shell out to `file`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Python built-in [`mimetypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html) module for this. I believe this module relies solely on the file *name* and not its *contents*.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) library:

```
>>> mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
>>> mime.from_file("testdata/test.pdf")
'application/pdf'
```

Comment: It's not a builtin module. Did you read the installation instructions at the link I provided? You can ``pip install python-magic`` or ``easy_install python-magic``

Comment: @Eng_Engineer the link has installation instructions for windows

Comment: :Sorry but in this link i don't know what can i download exactly to install magic.dll(http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @Eng_Engineer try [this link](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/getgnuwin32/getgnuwin32/0.6.30/GetGnuWin32-0.6.3.exe?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fgetgnuwin32%2Ffiles%2Fgetgnuwin32%2F0.6.30%2F&ts=1332701160&use_mirror=voxel)

Comment: :i installed  Automated gnuwin32 download tool from this link,what should i do next step?

Comment: magic1.dll, regex2.dll and zlib1.dll all need to be in system32 directory

Comment: these two files aren't exist in the GetGnuWin32,BTW i used mime=mimetypes.guess_type(name)[0] to get the mime type and it's worked correctly,Thanks for your help.

Comment: those files are definitely part of gnuwin32. just note that mimetypes relies on the file extension, not the file contents itself